# Edit the link of a XML Entity with java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am trying to edit the link of an entity in a XML file with Java.

In fact, the original link is an internet link and I would like to convert it into a local link when the document is getting parsed.
By the way, I will download the content that we can get at this link.

This is the original kind of link :

```
<!ENTITY % ISOEntities PUBLIC "ISO 8879-1986//ENTITIES ISO Character Entities 20030531//EN//XML" "http://www.website.com/category/xml_schema/ISOEntities">
```

This is the result i would like to have

```
<!ENTITY % ISOEntities PUBLIC "ISO 8879-1986//ENTITIES ISO Character Entities 20030531//EN//XML" "C:\data\xml\entities\ISOEntities">
```

So what I would like to do here is basically when the original link is detected, I would like to import the data ISOEntities from the local link (and not the internet link) but, without changing the original link (I will not write in the file to change the link).

How can i do that ?
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate way will vary depending which XML library you are using to parse the data, but the essential concept is to plug in some configuration to your parser that intercepts requests to load a particular entity and redirects them to the local cached copy.  For the SAX and DOM parsers of `javax.xml.parsers` this means an `EntityResolver`:

```
EntityResolver resolver = new EntityResolver() {
  public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) {
    if("ISO 8879-1986//ENTITIES ISO Character Entities 20030531//EN//XML".equals(publicId)) {
      return new InputSource("file:/C:/data/xml/entities/ISOEntities");
    } else {
      return null; // use the default resolution logic
    }
  }
};
```

You can pass that entity resolver to the `XMLReader` (for SAX) or the `DocumentBuilder` (for DOM) and it will load the ISO entities from your local copy.  The same mechanism will work for any other XML library that uses SAX or DOM internally to do its parsing (e.g. JDOM, Dom4J, XOM, ...) if you can pass in a suitably-configured `XMLReader` with your custom entity resolver.